# What's the safe, easy way to install noweb on Windows 10?

Tags: noweb

Apparently there's only [one person](http://www.jim-pettigrew.com/noweb/install/) that managed to do it.  I'm following his installations step by step precisely, but I do not have the iconc compiler.  Following the instructions of the Makefile, I'm using icont (which I do have), but then Jim's instructions do not work at all.

```
$ make install
[...]
cp totex disambiguate noidx tohtml elide l2h docs2comments autodefs.tex autodefs.icon autodefs.yacc autodefs.sml autodefs.pascal autodefs.promela autodefs.lrtl autodefs.asdl autodefs.mmix xchunks pipedocs /c/nowebFiles/usr/local/noweb/lib
cp: cannot stat `totex': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `disambiguate': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `noidx': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `tohtml': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `elide': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `l2h': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `docs2comments': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `xchunks': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `pipedocs': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Melba/noweb-2.11b/src/icon'
make: *** [install-code] Error 2
```

The problem here is that `icont` creates `totex.icx` and not `totex`.  Is this due to my not having `iconc` and am using `icont` instead?  I installed icont from [its homepage](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/index.htm) and it did not seem to come with `iconc`.  What should I do?

Just so you know: I've changed the `lib/Makefile` to call these programs as `totex.icx` and so I'm able to get the whole thing to build, but noweave doesn't work then, so I did it all from scratch and stopping to this point above to ask this question here because the only I thing I have different from Jim is that he might have had the `iconc` compiler and I don't.  (He's also on Windows 7 apparently, but I don't think that makes any difference at all here.)  Thank you!

Comment: [The noweb FAQ](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/FAQ.html) isn't too encouraging. All in all I would suggest that this is likely to be an uphill battle, due to the extreme age of the project and its relative obscurity. Wish I could help though!

Comment: Yup.  Thanks a lot, though.  I think I'm going to give up and give CWEB a try.

Comment: For the record, I eventually gave up --- I tried cygwin and msys.  [These instructions](http://www.jim-pettigrew.com/noweb/install/) didn't work for me on Windows 10 and maybe I'll come back here to report the exact problem --- I don't remember anymore.  CWEB works, but TeX is not prepared to deal with UTF-8 --- a nuisance. Other TeX distributions such as XeTeX did not work with the CWEB boilerplate.  So I'm still resorting to UNIX to run noweb.  Noweb's contribution `dpp` for C code pretty printing needs improvements.  Maybe I'll work on it.  (Though it's written in the post-modern language.)

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using Windows 10 and I've installed the Debian linux environment from the Microsoft Store (weird to type that). This is under the Windows SubsystemforLinux (WSL). I first updated the default software, as they recommend:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Following that, I installed aptitude, the Debian package manager I prefer (`apt-get install aptitude`), then emacs and noweb. (I use both for almost all my work.) Installing noweb, pulls in tex and other supporting programs into the WSL .

I just created a simple noweb file and noweave produced compilable tex, which worked fine with pdflatex. Thus, it appears to be much easier now to get noweb to work on Windows 10.

A potential caveat is that I don't yet fully understand how the two systems (native Windows 10 and WSL linux subsystem) interact together. Earlier today, I found that I couldn't not save a file from Emacs running in the native Windows 10 environment to the WSL Debian linux environment. But I can save a file to the native Windows 10 file system from WSL linux Emacs. So while one can now relatively easily install noweb on Windows 10, it may be too cumbersome a workflow.